# Laravel: Change or add a scheduled command dynamically

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, scheduler

I want to schedule an existing command in Laravel when a user successfully added data to the database. (after $data->save()) I assume that I'll have to schedule the new task from within my controller (where I create the data for the DB) instead of the Kernel. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Artisan::call('some:command', ['with' => 'many', 'other' => 'arguments'])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So where do I define the cron itself? 
Let's say a user has added a new event to a calendar. 
I want to send a mail on the day the event takes place. 
How would I do that? Or should I just constantly check the events in the table and compare them with today's date?
Thanks!

Comment: There are several ways to do it actually, you may consider to put it into a queue with a delay and it will be executed on that day. You may save every  "calendar event" it into a database table then your every-minute-worker scheduler may parse that table and send the time-to-send emails.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot!